# Asympotic for the summatory function $\sum_{k<n, \gcd(k,n)=1}{\Omega(k)}$

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, coprime

I am interested in finding an asymptotic for the following summatory function over $\Omega(n)$, which counts the total number of prime factors of $n$ honoring their multiplicity:

$$\sum_{k<n, \gcd(k,n)=1}{\Omega(k)}$$

Therefore, I want to find an asymptotic for the summatory function of $\Omega(k)$, where $k$ runs over the integers relatively prime to $n$ less than $n$.

In Hardy and Wright, the following asymptotic is computed:

$$\sum_{n\leq x}{\Omega(n)}=x\log\log x + B_2x + o(x)$$

Where $B_2\approx 1.0345061758$

However, I do not know how to proceed, or if there is some reference where the asymptotic is already computed. Any help will be welcomed.

Thanks in advance!